# Top N items in every month - BIGQUERY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a big query program below;

```
WITH cte AS(
SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT project_name,
    SUM(reward_value) AS total_reward_value,
    DATE_TRUNC(date_signing, MONTH) as month,
    date_signing,
    Row_number() over (partition by DATE_TRUNC(date_signing, MONTH)
                                          order by SUM(reward_value) desc) AS rank
      FROM `deals`
    WHERE CAST(date_signing as DATE) > '2019-12-31' 
    AND CAST(date_signing as DATE) < '2020-02-01'
    AND target_category = 'achieved'
    AND project_name IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY project_name, month, date_signing
  )
)

SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rank <= 5
```

that returns the following result:

[image: 1]

While I expect to have each unique project to be SUM within each month and then I filter only the top 5.

Something like this:

[image: 2]

I got the following error if the date_signing grouping is removed
PARTITION BY expression references column date_signing which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [16:48]

Any hints what should be corrected will be appreciated!

Comment: you are grouping by ` date_signing` , I think you don't want that , also its not a great idea to use column orders in group by or order by statements , make it hard to read and maintain

Comment: I edited my question to add the intention of having the 'date_signing' in the group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more subquery maybe then?

```
WITH cte AS(
  SELECT project_name,
    SUM(reward_value) as reward_sum,
    DATE_TRUNC(date_signing, MONTH) as month
  FROM `deals`
  WHERE CAST(date_signing as DATE) > '2019-12-31' 
    AND CAST(date_signing as DATE) < '2020-02-01'
    AND target_category = 'achieved'
    AND project_name IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY project_name, month
),
ranks AS (
  SELECT 
    project_name,
    reward_sum,
    month,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY month ORDER BY reward_sum DESC) AS rank
)
SELECT * 
FROM ranks 
WHERE rank <= 5
```

Comment: the intention I added date_signing is to solve this error n big query;
PARTITION BY expression references column date_signing which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [16:48] , updated my question for this.

Comment: One more subquery maybe then?

Comment: it worked, what I needed was the second CTE, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

yeah you can't do that , yo can show the last signing date instead:

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT project_name,
           SUM(reward_value),
           DATE_TRUNC(date_signing, MONTH) as month,
           MAX(date_signing) as last_signing_date,
           Row_number() over (partition by DATE_TRUNC(date_signing, MONTH)
                                          order by SUM(reward_value) desc) AS rank
    FROM `deals`
    WHERE CAST(date_signing as DATE) > '2019-12-31' 
        AND CAST(date_signing as DATE) < '2020-02-01'
        AND target_category = 'achieved'
        AND project_name IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY project_name, month
  
)

SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rank <= 5
```